# CasperJS doesn't load content injected by Angular router

Tags: angular, docker, phantomjs, casperjs, functional-testing

I'm preparing an [example project](https://github.com/emmetog/demo-docker-microservice-app/) on GitHub to accompany a course that I'm working on about how to write functional tests for dockerized applications. The application has a part which is an Angular2 single-page app, I'm trying to test this app with CasperJS (I've also tried with Behat with same problem explained below).

When running the tests in CasperJS it's as if the routing in Angular doesn't load for the tests, by that I mean that I can assert that things in the index template exist (like the page title for example) but things inside the `<app-root></app-root>` tags don't load for the tests.

### The code

Here is the index template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TestProject</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

The test is:

```
casper.test.begin('Tests homepage structure', function suite(test) {

    casper.start('http://web', function() {

        // This works because the title is set in the "parent" template.
        test.assertTitle("TestProject", "Title is correct");

        casper.wait(2000);

        // This fails, I'm guessing because the h2 is only in the "child" template,
        // it seems that CasperJS doesn't render the angular2 app correctly
        // and the child route templates are not injected into the page correctly.
        test.assertVisible('h2');
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

Here's the output of the test:

```
Test file: homepage.js                                                          
# Tests homepage structure
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
PASS Tests homepage structure (NaN test)
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://web/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://web/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://web/"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2 http://web/ (HTTP 200)
PASS Title is correct
FAIL Selector is visible
#    type: assertVisible
#    file: homepage.js
#    subject: false
#    selector: "h2"
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2: done in 178ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/3 http://web/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 3/3: done in 196ms.
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 2000ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 2215ms
```

Note that these tests and the web are running inside docker containers, that's why the hostname in the code above is "web" and not an IP.

The application is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/emmetog/demo-docker-microservice-app/). To run the application do `docker-compose up` in the root and browse to http://127.0.0.1:81/. To run the CasperJS tests run `./tests/web/run_functional_test.sh`, you don't need to run `docker-compose up` beforehand.

#### Stuff tried

I have tried to see if CasperJS is running into a problem by outputting any console errors on CasperJS's loading of the page but I haven't found anything suspicious.

The application works perfectly when run in the browser, I can see the content that the router injected into the index template.

I have tried using [resurrectio](https://github.com/ebrehault/resurrectio) to visit my page in Chrome, click a few things and then export this test directly to a CasperJS test file, this automatically generated test fails for the same reason, the content which is injected by the router is not accessible by CasperJS.

I have tried using Behat and Selenium with similar results. This suggests that the problem is not with CasperJS/PhantomJS (maybe Angular setup?).

### The question

I'm no PhantomJS/Selenium expert but I understood that they can render javascript and so it's normal to expect that CasperJS and Behat should be able to run assertions on things that the Angular router inserts into the page, am I wrong in assuming this?

If not, what is going on with my tests? Why can't the CasperJS tests run assertions against the templates in the routes?

Comment: PhantomJS is not the best choice, I would suggest you use `selenium/standalone-chrome` or `selenium/standalone-firefox` docker images for your testing. You don't want to be solving issues on headless browser when today docker allows you to have a near headless solution

Answer (score 0):

In the end the problem was a simple one, the simple ones are usually the ones that make you pull your hair out.

From within my web application I was using "127.0.0.1:82" as the connection string of the API. This worked in local because the docker-compose file mapped port 82 of the host but I wasn't mapping port 82 for the tests, so the web couldn't connect to the API. The fix is [here](https://github.com/emmetog/demo-docker-microservice-app/commit/8fb939ca6170adfcf4792d25573d8297138b66d3#diff-419a583fd2f249c6ae585fa309dae5f5R11).

> I'm no PhantomJS/Selenium expert but I understood that they can render javascript and so it's normal to expect that CasperJS and Behat should be able to run assertions on things that the Angular router inserts into the page, am I wrong in assuming this?

I was of course correct in assuming this.